# postgis 2.3 installation with postgres 9.6 ubuntu 18.04

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.6, ubuntu-18.04, postgis-installation

I have been trying to install postgis 2.3 with postgres 9.6 on ubuntu 18.04 with command

`sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.3`

but got an error

```
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.3
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.3'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.3'
```

I have postgres 9.6 installed.

Answer (score -1):

Error seems to be network or repository related.
Download the postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.3 package to local storage and install it.

For. example:

```
/path/to/postgis2_96-2.3.2-1.rhel7.x86_64.rpm
sudo alien --install /path/to/postgis2_96-2.3.2-1.rhel7.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Not helpful, where do we get the rpm, what is alien?